# Can unicode characters requiring the number pad, e.g. U+3041, be typed using the On-Screen Keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, unicode, on-screen-keyboard

Suppose that I want to type 'ぁ' *Unicode U+3041) using Window 10's On-Screen Keyboard without changing my language away from US English. Can it be done?

As far as my research indicates, this would require holding ALT, which I believe to be impossible.

Comment: Alt codes don't open up the world of unicode. It's a very limited set of 'advanced' characters - https://www.alt-codes.net

Comment: BTW, that's a good reason to be careful when using a nonstandard keyboard layout for setting login password -- a character chosen from that keyboard might not be available at login (as I found out, requiring me to remove the local Windows password to reset it).

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it, and the answer is No.

The OSK does not allow to keep the Alt key pressed, so pressing Alt and
the `3`, you cannot type the rest of the string `3041` in Alt mode.
The Alt modifier only works for single key press.

Some third-party
[On-Screen Keyboard Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-on-screen-keyboard/)
may have this capability, but I have no experience with them.